# Drop 50% of rows containing a keyword

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which contains a column 'location' with countries.

```
     id   location
0   001   United State
1   002   United State
2   003   Germany
3   004   Brazil
4   005   China
```

Now I only want the rows with specific countries.
I did this like this:

```
df2 = df[(df['location'].str.contains('United States')) | (df['location'].str.contains('Germany'))
```

That works.

Now I want only half of the rows with 'United States'.

(The reason is I have a really large dataset and most of the rows are 'United States'. For the sake of performance for further operations i want to cut half of it or just any %.)

Can anyone help me do that in a fast and clean way? Im sturggling.
TY <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sample` for that, together with `drop`

```
df.drop(df[df['location'] == 'United State']).sample(frac=.5).index)
```

The filter inside, returns ALL the rows that have values equal to 'United State'. Then the sample takes randomly 50% of those and the index will return the index number which then will be used to drop those rows.

Comment: Note that dropping rows with 50% *probability* isn't quite the same as dropping 50% of rows.  It probably will be very close if your data set is large enough, which might be fine.

Comment: Pandas sample will return 50% of the rows (as a fraction). I don't think that probability is anywhere mentioned in the answer. But generally speaking, you are right.